# Regex for validating SQL

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I am writing a regex to validate that a name should be given when defining INDEX, KEY and UNIQUE while creating a new table. Some of the valid syntaxes are

```
KEY `id` (`id`),     
INDEX name (`name`),    
UNIQUE idx (`id`),     
UNIQUE KEY name (`name`),
```

Invalid syntaxes are

```
UNIQUE KEY (`name`),   
INDEX (`designation`),     
UNIQUE (`status`),
```

because there is no name provided while defining them.

I came up with a regex like this

> (?i)(?:UNIQUE\s+KEY|UNIQUE\s+INDEX|KEY|INDEX|UNIQUE)\s*`?\w+`?\s*\(

But it matches

> UNIQUE KEY (`name`),

also. Is there anyway I can improve the regex not to match the above string?

Comment: Try [`(?:KEY\s+\`[^\`]*\`|(?:INDEX|UNIQUE\s+KEY)\s+\w+|UNIQUE\s+(?!KEY\s*\()\w+)\s*\(\`[^\`]*\`\)`](https://regex101.com/r/vC8bG2/2)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. When I tried ur regex, I got error for unbalanced paranthesis.

Comment: Did you copy it from here? It must be a copy/paste issue. It works at the regex101.com. Using `\`` is tricky inside comments.

Comment: Thanks anyway @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Your "invalid" syntaxes are quite valid.  I almost never explicitly name indexes.

Comment: @RickJames You are correct. This is not about validity of the syntax. We just need to enforce that a name should be given for an index when defined so that it would be easy for locating them during migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead after the first UNIQUE so that it would try the second OR and only then matches UNIQUE KEY.

```
(?i)(?:INDEX|UNIQUE(?! KEY)|UNIQUE KEY|KEY)\s+\W?[\w ]+\W?\s+\(\W?[\w ]+\W?\)
```

And the reverse, if you want to find the nameless which you pointed out as invalid:

```
(?i)(?:INDEX|UNIQUE(?! KEY)|UNIQUE KEY|KEY)\s+\(\W?[\w ]+\W?\)
```